# error when making my own activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to test an activation function on MNIST data 
but it gave an error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Here is my activation function :

```
def fun1(x):
    return np.sqrt(x) if x>=0 else (-(np.sqrt(-x)))
```

and here is the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2),
             input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(fun1))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(fun1))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(w_l2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(fun1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: Do you have a line for the error? Where does it happen?

Comment: it happens after excuting the model code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the custom activation function, `x` is a tensor, so Keras `backend` methods need to be used instead of numpy. Your implementation could be changed to something like this:

```
from keras import backend as K
def fun1(x):
    return K.sqrt(K.abs(x))
```

For more examples, look at Keras defined activations:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py